# Define a list of elements in an xsd schema

Tags: xsd

This portion of my schema is giving me trouble:

```
        <xs:element name="newrecipients">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:choice>
                    <xs:element name="csv" type="xs:string" />
                    <!-- List of recipients -->
                </xs:choice>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
```

The list of recipients is a list of things like:

```
<recipient>
    <field1>...</field1>
    ...
    <fieldN>...</field>
</recipient>
```

where the tag recipient could contain random sequence of tags unknown to the schema. So I used something like

```
  <xs:element name="recipient">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:any minOccurs="1"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
```

The problem is that I don't how to define a list of recipients. I know `<xs:list>` but I can't understand how to use it in this case because usually I see something like

```
<xs:element name="intvalues" type="valuelist">

<xs:simpleType name="valuelist">
  <xs:list itemType="xs:integer"/>
</xs:simpleType>

</xs:schema>
```

where you have to define an element that contains the list. I want directly `csv` OR directly the `list`.

What am I missing? Thanks.

EDIT: output example

This:

```
<newrecipients>
    <csv>myrecipients.csv</csv>
</newrecipients>
```

or this:

```
<newrecipients>
    <recipient>
        <field1>...</field1>
        ...
        <fieldN>...</field>
    </recipient>
    ...
    <recipient>
        <field1>...</field1>
        ...
        <fieldN>...</field>
    </recipient>
</newrecipients>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure if it is valid inside a `xsd:choice` element:

```
<xs:element name="newrecipients">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice>
            <xs:element name="csv" type="xs:string" />
            <!-- List of recipients -->
            <xs:element name="recipient" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:any minOccurs="1"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

For sure you can use this solution wrapping the elements declarations inside a `xsd:sequence` tag, but I don't know if you want the list to exists if and only if the csv element is missing.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I added an example of what I want. I think with your example I can have only one recipient tag since is a choice?

Comment: I found this example: http://xmlzoo.net/xsd/?xml=16q.xml
From what is stated there it seems that even if you have a xsd:choice you can still specify that a certain element can be repeated several times setting the maxOccurs value at unbounded. So the solution should work.